# How to remove or destroy SKSpriteNode once it disappears from screen

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I am making a ***Flappy Bird*** kind of a game using **Swift 3**. I spawn pipes with the help of a function 'makePipes()' which I'm calling every 3 seconds with the a timer. The 'makePipes()' function makes SKSpriteNode for the Pipes and moves them from right of the screen to left of the screen.
What I wanna do is, destroy the Node of the Pipe after it has vanished from the screen or after it has completed its movement from one side of the screen to other.

Another solution could be to Re-use the pipes once they have moved from right to left.

```
pipe1.run(movePipes) { 
        self.pipe1.removeFromParent()
    }
```

I tried the above solution and it does not work. It shows weird blinking lines across the screen and pipes become weirdly and randomly placed instead of uniform.

Any help is appreciated. I'm very new to iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have done something like this:-

```
movePipesForward = SKAction.moveByX(-dx, y: 0 ,duration: duration)
removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()
moveForwardAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipesForward, removePipes])
pipe1.runAction(moveForwardAndRemove)
self.addChild(pipe)
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Although, could I have used a non repeating timer to call another function which removes the pipes after the desired amount of time?

Comment: Removing pipes after a desired amount of time can work provided, if the movement of pipes and the time are in sync, which is more of hit and trial..